# how to add kendo window minimize and maximize action

Tags: kendo-ui, callback

I am using the below method to initiate a kwindow instance:

```
function initWindow() {
    const kwindow = self.$window.getKendoWindow(); <--- I have tried adding the added action in the getKendoWindow(i.e. here)

    kwindow.bind('close', (event) => {
      setTimeout(close.bind(self, event));
    });

    kwindow.one('open', startProgress);

    return kwindow;
  }
```

How could I add the **minimize** icon / `action` within this format?

---

*i.e.* **recent attempt below:** Yes, I know the documentation shows one way of adding the actions to kwindows setup a certain way, but where I'm integrating these they aren't setup like that.

```
const kwindow = self.$window.getKendoWindow({
  actions: ["Minimize"], <-- no errors but does nothing
});
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to do. Kendo Windows already support maximize and minimize, see https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/window/configuration/actions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using [setOptions](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/window/methods/setoptions)

> Allows the Window to be configured with new options.

```
const kwindow = self.$window.getKendoWindow();
kwindow.setOptions({
    actions: ["Minimize", "Maximize"]
});
```